# No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. oro commerce

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, orocommerce

I'm following this documentation to deploy ORO on my local host.
https://laptrinhx.com/installing-orocommerce-b2b-application-583947541/

when i execute
'''
composer install --prefer-dist
'''
this command it gives me the error

No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.

i have tried all the methods available but nothing's working for me kindly can someone guide me on it?

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no "composer.lock" file (I don't see it in the repository), the Composer will use "composer.json", it is a normal behavior.
You can use "composer update" if there is no "composer.lock" file

Comment: The `composer.lock` file is in the repository, but not for the master branch. Here is the  latest stable tag for today with the lock: https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce-application/tree/4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official documentation to install the OroCommerce application.

The article you are referring to has a big issue. It proposes to install the app from the master branch that is unstable and updated every day, and therefore it doesn't have the composer.lock file.

```
git clone https://github.com/orocommerce/orocommerce-application.git .
```

Instead of the `master` branch, we recommend installing the latest stable LTS version. Here is the official [OroCommerce installation guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/).

If you follow the above guide, the lock file will be in place as it is provided for all the stable releases.